# Extern delphi dll not working on windows server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, delphi, dll, windows-server-2012

We have a problem with extern DLL written in Delphi that we're using in ASP.NET MVC4 C# application. Strange thing is that DLL is working fine and returns list of strings on developer machine but when we put it on web server it doesn't returning anything.

On local we are using: IIS 7,ASP.NET 4.0, Windows 7.5, SQL Server 2008 R2
On web we are using: IIS 8, ASP.NET 4.0, Windows server 2012, SQL Server 2008 R2

Here is the code:

```
[DllImport("C:\\EMSStructureSearch\\BL\\DLL\\StructureHandler.dll")]
public static extern int StructureSearch(byte[] NamelessParameter1, StringBuilder NamelessParameter2, int NamelessParameter3);
        public ActionResult AdvStructureSearch(string query, string exactsearch, string stereo,GridDescriptor request)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AdvancedSearchFilter"] = null;
            var tmp = BreadcrumbNavigationGetSet();
            AdvSearchFiltersAll filters = new AdvSearchFiltersAll();
            if (filters.StructureSearch == null)
            {
                filters.StructureSearch = new AdvStructureSearch();
            }
            filters.StructureSearch.Query = query;
            filters.StructureSearch.Exactsearch = exactsearch;
            filters.StructureSearch.Stereo = stereo;
            filters = BreadcrumbNavigationGetSet(filters);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(524288);
            byte[] bytesData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("query=" + query + ";exactsearch=" + exactsearch + ";stereo=" + stereo + "\0");
           int result= StructureSearch(bytesData, sb, sb.Capacity);
           string  recordIds = sb.Replace(";",",").ToString().Trim().TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: Did you already check the dll file properties if it has been blocked for security reasons because it has been uploaded from network? Blocked files show a button labeled "unblock" on the first property tab.

Comment: Yes, I have checked DLL file properties. That is OK.

Comment: Next thing to check: 32-Bit vs. 64-Bit: Did you try to have your sites' application pool running on 32-Bit?

Comment: Our application can work only on 64-Bit but DLL is also 64-Bit.

Comment: Try some debugging. Find out some meaningful information. Is the DLL loading? If the function being called? What happens inside the function when it is called? So, just the basic first debugging steps.

Comment: You surely checked IIS log or Windows event logs

Comment: Same environment (IIS, ASP.NET, operating system) on developer machine?